# Theory behind confidence interval algorithm

Tags: statistics

Why do we need to increase confidence level before applying it to a quantile function? Specifically, I want to understand the theory behind [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval#Practical_example)(0.95=>0.975) transformation:$$p=1-\frac{\alpha}{2}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is that the distribution is symmetric (or mostly so).  Thus, if the $95$th percentile is a certain amount $z$ above the mean, then the $5$th percentile is that same amount $z$ below the mean.

In consequence, the range between $-z$ and $+z$ amounts to $95-5 = 90$ percent of the population.  The $90$ percent confidence interval, in other words, lies between $-z$ and $+z$.  Note that the $90$ percent confidence interval yields the same value of $z$ as the $95$th percentile.  In general, the $100-2x$ confidence interval would yield the same value of $z$ as the $100-x$th percentile.

Another way of seeing this is that the $100-x$th percentile captures everything from $-\infty$ to $+z$; in particular, it captures the far left tail, which includes $x$ percent of the population (but omits the far right tail, which also has $x$ percent).  The $100-2x$ confidence interval leaves out both the far left tail and the far right tail, which is *why* it only has $100-2x$ percent of the population.